# Detection of Cycles without a Center in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

In my classes in dynamical systems theory, we were taught how to detect cycles or cyclic behavior in an ODE (be it dampened, sustained or growing) around a fixed point by looking at the eigenvalues for that point (their imaginary component in particular).

But in higher dimensional systems cycles need not have a center, and in practice one often does not even always know the location of a center even if it exists.

Are there any non-local techniques for identifying cyclic behavior in an ODE which would allow me to detect a cycle without a center? Would such techniques similarly allow me to identify strange attractors?

Comment: Have you learnt about the Poincare-Bendixson criterion?

Comment: Poincare-Bendixson applies for two dimensional systems only.

Comment: Ah, I should have read the question more carefully, I missed the "higher dimensional systems" part.

Comment: would you not expect the divergence of the vector field over a large sphere to be negative?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nontrivial problem in general: to analyze limit cycles in systems of dimension $d\geq 3$. Still there is a lot of research in this direction. A great source of various material is [Periodic Motions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942041) by Miklos Farkas.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out. I figured this is a hard problem but I was hoping for _any_ kind of heuristic to help tackle it, however brute forced.